# Should the tag for Poco's Udon World be changed to correct its spelling?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I believe the tag for the series *Poco's Udon World* is misspelled.  It spells the character's name as "Poko" [pokos-udon-world].  The tag is currently associated with two questions, and there is no tag using the "poco" spelling.

I could find no English sources which use the "k" instead of "c".  The following sources use "c", which I feel makes it definitive.

- Crunchyroll, as seen in this cover art:

[image: Poco's Udon World cover art]

- the English subtitles within the episodes themselves use "Poco" (time mark 13:34 of [episode 2](http://www.crunchyroll.com/pocos-udon-world/episode-2-kotoden-722097))

[image: Poco gets his name]

- its English [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poco's_Udon_World) uses Poco
- its [My Anime List page](https://myanimelist.net/anime/32673/Udon_no_Kuni_no_Kiniro_Kemari) uses Poco (as well as alternative titles without "Poco", *Udon no Kuni no Kiniro Kemari* and the original うどんの国の金色毛鞠 )

I'm guessing I over-researched this.  Both existing questions are short and were posted by @Mindwin . They internally use the "Poko" spelling. This was unfortunate because previously I had hunted for questions about this series and could not find any.

Comment: I left a comment on one of @Mindwin 's questions letting him know of this post.  Perhaps I missed it, but there seemed no way to leave him a private message or email from his user page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I renamed the tag. I left [pokos-udon-world] as a synonym pointing to [pocos-udon-world] because why not.